# Can't change ruby version with rbenv on mac

Tags: ruby, rbenv

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
/Users/mac_pro/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I'am trying to do `rbenv global 2.5.8` and after

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

but my version is always -

```
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

i need 2.5.8 version

Comment: use `rvm` to manage ruby version better on mac

Comment: What's the output for `rbenv global`, `rbenv local` and `rbenv shell`?

Comment: Did you use ruby-build or similar to *build* Ruby 2.5.8? Does `rbenv versions` even list it as an available option?

Comment: @infokksonkz did my answer help you? If so, would you please be so nice an accept it?

Answer (score 1):

On your cmd write this command:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
```

Then write this to refresh or maybe close the terminal and re-open it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now check your version with `ruby -v`

Answer (score 0):

The `rbenv global` command only specifies, which ruby version should be used globally.
You also need to install this version with `rbenv install 2.5.8`.